# How can i set custom theme for whole application at run time on single click?

Tags: android

How to change the theme without recalling activity?

Suppose I have two activities A and B. I am calling activity B from activity A. From activity B I am changing the theme and by doing `recreate()` activity B's theme gets changed. But how can I change the theme of activity A that is in the back stack?

I don't want to recall activity A from activity B.

Comment: why do you want to change theme when it's back stack already. What's the use case exactly?

Comment: i am changing theme from activity B. How can i change theme of activity A without calling it via intent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is when you go back from your `Activity B` to `Activity A` this last one will get resumed. So in the `onResume` method you will need to check if the theme as changed and apply it to your activity.

**Here is an example:**

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int mTheme;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mTheme = getCurrentTheme();
        setTheme(mTheme);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        int currentTheme = getCurrentTheme();

        // If the theme has changed, we need to apply it
        if (mTheme != currentTheme) {
            // Recreate activity
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is PreferencesUtils and Manager ?

Comment: Is the way I store my current theme ID. I simplify the code.

Comment: SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        int appColor = app_preferences.getInt("color", 0);
        int appTheme = app_preferences.getInt("theme", 0);

        int themeColor = appColor;
        int constant.color = appColor;

        if (themeColor == 0){
            setTheme(Constant.theme);
        }else if (appTheme == 0){
            setTheme(Constant.theme);
        }else{
            setTheme(appTheme);
        }

Comment: currently i am using above code to set theme before activities super.onCreale()

Comment: in onResume you are recreating activity. can we set theme without recreating the activity ?

Comment: Not possible. Your activity was created with a context that has a reference for a theme. In order to apply the changes from another, te activity needs to be recreated.